# C#. webClient не сохраняет файл, если есть операция с файлом

Tags: c#

Если просто:

```
wClient.DownloadFile(url, path);
```

Сохраняет файл, он не пустой.
А если так:

```
wClient.DownloadFile(url, path);
                    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Truncate))
                    {

                    };
```

То файл создаёт, но файл всегда пустой. Оба действия лежат в Task, Task вызывается нажатием на кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем собственно вопрос? FileMode.Truncate указывает, что нужно открыть существующий файл и отбросить его содержимое, то есть длина файла становится 0 байт. То есть сначала вы скачиваете файл, а потом сразу удаляете его.

Comment: спасибо, это может быть ответом. 
к слову, мне нужно удалять файл, если он пустой кодом внутри uses. какой мне писать тогда FileMode?

Comment: FileMode.Append, спасибо